# Windows 10 + ssh + Alt Gr

Tags: windows-10, ssh

I am using Windows 10 ssh client to access multiple linux servers (Ubuntu and Debian), my keyboard is the Portuguese layout (PT) and the symbols @, {, [,],} need to be used with Alt Gr (Right Alt).

In cmd, powershell or CMder (which I use), these symbols work correctly, but when accessing any server with ssh stops working

When I use Putty or plink they also work normally.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem with windows ssh?